# Select users who did a purchase after a search where some conditions apply in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this case: users are making searches on the website and some of them purchase. How would you select users over 18 who did a **search** without a following **purchase** where purchase condition is true and search session = purchase session

This selects users with search events and age over 18.

```
select DISTINCT ON (id) id, email, users.age, events.type, events.createdon 
from users 
   LEFT JOIN events ON events.user = users.users 
where events.type='search' 
  and age>18 
  and events.condition is true
```

How would I add the condition that they did a **search** event previously in the same session?

The table structure for events:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| user |   event   |    date    | condition | session |
------------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |  search   | 08-10-2013 |   true    |    A    |
|  1   |  search   | 08-10-2013 |   true    |    A    |
|  2   |  search   | 08-10-2013 |   false   |    B    |
|  2   | purchase  | 09-10-2013 |   false   |    A    |
|  2   |  search   | 09-10-2013 |   true    |    C    |
|  1   | purchase  | 09-10-2013 |   true    |    A    |
|  3   |  search   | 09-10-2013 |   false   |    D    |
|  2   |  search   | 10-10-2013 |   true    |    H    |
|  4   |  search   | 10-10-2013 |   false   |    E    |
|  4   |  search   | 10-10-2013 |   false   |    E    |
|  3   |  search   | 11-10-2013 |   true    |    D    |
|  2   |  other    | 11-10-2013 |   true    |    H    |
|  1   |  search   | 11-10-2013 |   true    |    F    |
|  1   | purchase  | 12-10-2013 |   true    |    F    |
|  3   | purchase  | 12-10-2013 |   false   |    D    |
|  4   |  search   | 12-10-2013 |   true    |    G    |    
|  2   |  other    | 12-10-2013 |   true    |    A    |   
-----------------------------------------------------
```

and the user table is:

```
------------------------
| user | email  | age  |
------------------------
|  1   |   a    |  22  |
|  2   |   b    |  34  |
|  3   |   c    |  15  |
|  4   |   d    |  44  |
|  5   |   e    |  39  |
------------------------
```

The result should be 2 and 4:

```
1    a   -> NO because did purchase with condition=true
2    b   -> YES because did search, did purchase BUT condition=false
3    c   -> NO because did search, did purchase with condition=false BUT age<18
4    d   -> YES because did search and no purchase
```

Thank you, I'm just starting with Postgres from Mongo and is much better!

UPDATE: corrected result for example

Comment: Not related, but: using `distinct on` without an order by is not a good idea.

Comment: Could you add expected result, please?

Comment: Yes, the results should be 1 and 3. 
2 is not correct because seesion for purchase is different than session from search

Comment: Sorry, only 1 is correct because 3 age is 15

Comment: You wrote: `search without a following purchase`, but in your results 1st user has search and purchase actions in same session. Is it correct?

Comment: What is the definition of _previous_ if the dates for search and purchase are the same ?

Comment: @joop Date is actually a timestamp, not only date.

Comment: @hedgesky i correct the example result

Comment: If a user did a search, then a purchase, then another search without a purchase (all in the same session), should that user be returned in the results?

Comment: @AndriyM yes, it should be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just data from `users` table:

```
select
    u.*
from users as u
where
    u.age > 18 and
    exists (
        select *
        from events as e1
        where 
            e1.user = u.user and e1.condition is true and
            e1.event = 'search' and
            not exists (
                select *
                from events as e2
                where
                    e2.user = u.user and e2.condition is true and
                    e2.event = 'purchase' and
                    e2.session = e1.session and e2.date > e1.date
            )
    )
```

if's also could be done like this:

```
select
    u.*
from users as u
where
    u.age > 18 and
    exists (
        select *           
        from (
            select
                max(case when e.event = 'search' then e.date end) as search_m_date,
                max(case when e.event = 'purchase' then e.date end) as purchase_m_date
            from events as e
            where e.user = u.user and e.condition is true
            group by e.session
        ) as a
        where
            a.search_m_date is not null and
            (a.purchase_m_date is null or a.search_m_date > a.purchase_m_date)
    )
```

but actually I like first one better

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/08127/13)</kbd>**

Comment: ...and `exists` should probably be changed to `not exists`.

Comment: changed query anyway :) previous one could work with `not exists`, but we have to check that user actually did a search (or user 5 will be in the results)

Comment: I have used the first one and it works. Is there a way to optimize the query for millions rows? It takes about 6-7 seconds on 5M and it's just at the beginning.

Comment: weel you have to build proper indexes to optimize it

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to go about building the complete query step by step:

1. Get all search events:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM events AS s
   WHERE event = 'search'
     AND condition IS TRUE
   ```
2. Filter out those that are followed by a successful purchase event:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM
     events AS s
   LEFT JOIN
     events AS p
     ON  s.user = p.user
     AND s.session = p.session
     AND p.event = 'purchase'
     AND p.condition IS TRUE
     AND p.date > s.date  -- this assumes that `date` stores both date and time
   WHERE s.event = 'search'
     AND s.condition IS TRUE
     AND p.event IS NULL
   ```
3. Get users from the `users` table whose IDs are returned in the previous result set and whose age is above 18:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM users
   WHERE age > 18
     AND user IN (
       SELECT
         s.user
       FROM
         events AS s
       LEFT JOIN
         events AS p
         ON  s.user = p.user
         AND s.session = p.session
         AND p.event = 'purchase'
         AND p.condition IS TRUE
         AND p.date > s.date
       WHERE s.event = 'search'
         AND s.condition IS TRUE
         AND p.event IS NULL
     )
   ;
   ```

This should give you the desired results although not necessarily in the most efficient way. You could play with the anti-join, which in this query is implemented using the `LEFT JOIN + WHERE IS NULL` technique, rewriting it with the `NOT EXISTS` one to see if that performs any better. Additionally, you could try rewriting the `IN` predicate with an equivalent `EXISTS` one. (Essentially, @Roman Pekar's first solution could be viewed as the result of both rewritings suggested.)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I actually improved my query using your LEFT JOIN example from point 3. Query time is not 55% percent lower :)